# Exact match on training phrase intent Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

The Training phrase only contains How to order but when I only type "order" it still shows or reply to me.
What can I do to make it reply to only very specific words?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQZzl.png)

If I didn't explain my problem well enough, here's a link on a guy that has the same problem and has better english compared to mine

https://www.reddit.com/r/Dialogflow/comments/dmy5x6/exact_match/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Click the option button (three dotted button) beside the save button inside the intent.
2. Click on 'disable ML'.

If Ml is disabled, The Intent will follow Rule-based grammar matching algorithm which means it will only match user expressions with the exact training phrases defined in the intent.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the keyword 'order' in the default fallback intent's training phrase and you should be fine. OR
2. You can also create a new Intent that handles only a specific keyword like 'order' in your case and add a quick reply saying did you mean how to order? Yes & No

> Hope this helps :) If you have some queries do drop a comment.

Comment: Hi, I was thinking that it can maybe spam in the mid conversations?

when a costumer says "when will my order arrive" the quick reply of yes or no will appear

so here comes the default fallback intent of order right? so it wont spam

Comment: You can handle for these cases in a separate intent with separate payload for these kind of quick reply button. I would recommend a Followup Intent but honestly I havn't really tried that.